# TinyIoC and release build

Tags: xamarin.android, tinyioc

I'm doing my first Release build, and am having problems with TinyIoC and resolving interfaces used via TinyIoC.

The architecture we've got is:

Universal.Mobile.Droid.application - main application

Universal.Mobile.Droid.Interfaces - contains definition of IUniversalMobileDroidDAO

Universal.Mobile.Droid.DAO.UltraliteDAO - contains implementation of 
IUniversalMobileDroidDAO

When I do a release build and deploy/run on my device, I get the error:

```
07-06 10:30:23.706 I/dalvikvm( 4783): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 12...
07-06 10:30:23.816 I/ActivityThread( 4783): Pub UniversalMonoPhone.UniversalMonoPhone.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
07-06 10:30:23.816 D/dalvikvm( 4783): Trying to load lib /data/data/UniversalMonoPhone.UniversalMonoPhone/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4104d468
07-06 10:30:23.846 D/dalvikvm( 4783): Added shared lib /data/data/UniversalMonoPhone.UniversalMonoPhone/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4104d468
07-06 10:30:23.846 W/MonoDroid-Debugger( 4783): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8977,server=y,embedding=1
07-06 10:30:23.866 W/MonoDroid-Debugger( 4783): Accepted stdout connection: 41
07-06 10:30:24.656 E/mono    ( 4783): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
07-06 10:30:24.656 E/mono    ( 4783): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
07-06 10:30:25.126 I/monodroid-gc( 4783): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
07-06 10:30:25.166 W/monodroid-gc( 4783): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
Loaded assembly: Universal Mono Phone.dll
Loaded assembly: Universal.Mobile.Droid.Interfaces.dll
Loaded assembly: Autoforms.Universal.Mobile.Core.Interfaces.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: Autoforms.Universal.Mobile.Core.Objects.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: Universal.Mobile.Droid.DAO.UltraliteDAO.dll
Loaded assembly: UltraliteForMono.dll
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
Unhandled Exception:

TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Autoforms.Universal.Mobile.Droid.Interfaces.IUniversalMobileDroidDAO
```

Do I need to tweak my build/linker/manifest to solve this?

Regards,

James

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to input from Atsushi on the Mono For Android forum for the solution.

What I needed to do was select 'SDK assemblies only' in Linking on the Project properties.

I was misreading the meaning of 'Linking' - thinking that this defines the assemblies to include, not the assemblies to exclude if not used! I think.

Comment: Linking is a post-build step that strips out any code that isn't actually referenced by your app to help cut down on the size. This can lead to problems when code isn't called explicitly, such as via reflection or (de)serialization. Some useful documentation about the linking process is available here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking